# I have attached image on mail. It's working perfectly on local server but not on live server [No email being sent] . What could be the reason?

Tags: c#

I have added this code in a controller method:

```
string imageDir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageDir"];

Attachment atc = new Attachment(imageDir + attech,MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

mail.Attachments.Add(atc);
```

I have added this in my `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="imageDir" value ="F:\IQCU2\IQCU2\Content\Uploads\"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Does the address of the file exist on the server?

Comment: I have given server address when publish it

Comment: "It's not working". Please edit your question to include the error you are getting. On which line is the error thrown? Are you actually getting an error, or is no eMail being sent, or is an eMail being sent without the attchment?

Comment: No email being sent. It's working perfectly when I run it on local server but not on live sever

Comment: Can you send an email from the server without an attachment?

Comment: Yes without image it works.

Comment: You should be able to learn what the problem is by subscribing to [SmtpClient.SendCompleted Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted?view=net-6.0) if using SmptClient as shown in the example in the link.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments?view=net-6.0) is a basic example of sending an email with attachment. Did you include this piece of code into your project?

```
 //Send the message.
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}",
            ex.ToString());
    }
```